# How to port from Arduino to AVR?

Tags: arduino, avr, atmel, arduino-ide

How can I port an Arduino library to the ATTiny family of microcontrollers? I'm using avrdude if that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use an Arduino support package for the family?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific procedure.  You should just try to compile the library and deal with the error messages one at a time.  You should generally look at the first error message printed by the compiler and fix that before moving on to the next.  The Arduino IDE defines a lot of things that are not available in a plain avr-gcc compiler (e.g. `digitalWrite`), so you will need to replace references to those things with something else.

If you have a more specific question about how to fix one of those error messages, feel free to post a new question on this site.